# casts datetime format in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, datetime, web

As the Laravel document, we can cast the value to DateTime.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-serialization#date-serialization

```
protected $casts = [
    'birthday' => 'date:Y-m-d',
    'joined_at' => 'datetime:Y-m-d H:00',
];
```

There result is :

`"2020-05-29 00:00:00"`
but i want to result like that:

`"2020-10-29T00:00"`

I can use Carbon with format `"Y-m-d\TH:i");`

if possible to format like `"2020-10-29T00:00"` if I don't use the Carbon?

any ideas will be appreciated.

Comment: please explain better your problem

Comment: @GiacomoM edited,  is it clear to you?

Answer (score 0):

As the Carbon documentation (https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-formatting) states. You can use `format()` function.

```php
$dt->format("Y-m-d\TH:i")
```

Comment: thank you for the answer but I dont want to use Carbon library. I just want to use in casts of Laravel.

Comment: Carbon is an extension of php DateTime library. You can use DateTime function